# Sql Server: timeout connection

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a problem of this type on the code below, when I try to execute it I am shown the following error. How can I go about solving this? What is this due to?
this series of code allows the implementation of the query within a c # program. 
how can this be resolved, I state that it always happens to me in some cases I run the code

**Exception:**

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The wait operation timed out
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption, Boolean shouldCacheForAlwaysEncrypted)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Myapp.Model.CapitoloModel.DuplicaCapitolo(Int32 IdPreventivo, Int32 IdCapitolo) in C:\Users\riccardo\Desktop\Progetti\Myapp\src\Myapp\Myapp\Model\CapitoloModel.cs:line 132
ClientConnectionId:b4f3d128-449f-40da-852e-bba9d0a12924
Error Number:-2,State:0,Class:11Myapp
```

**C# Code:**

```
public static bool DuplicaCapitolo(int IdPreventivo, int IdCapitolo)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = Database.Apriconnessione();
            SqlTransaction Transaction = conn.BeginTransaction();
            bool ret = true;
            try
            {
                const string QueryLastIdCapitolo = " SELECT count(*) + 1 FROM Capitolo  where IdPreventivo = @IdPreventivo ";
                SqlCommand cmdLastidCapitolo = new SqlCommand(QueryLastIdCapitolo, conn, Transaction);
                cmdLastidCapitolo.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdPreventivo", SqlDbType.Int).Value = IdPreventivo;
                int NumeroCapitoloLOAD = (int)cmdLastidCapitolo.ExecuteScalar();
                const string Query = "Select * from Capitolo where IdCapitolo=@IdCapitolo";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Query, conn, Transaction);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdCapitolo", IdCapitolo);
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);

                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    int IdPreventivoLOAD = int.Parse(dr["IdPreventivo"].ToString());
                    string TipologiaLOAD = dr["Tipologia"].ToString();
                    decimal PrezzoRiservatoLOAD = decimal.Parse(dr["PrezzoRiservato"].ToString());
                    string DescrizioneLOAD = dr["Descrizione"].ToString();
                    decimal RicaricoLOAD = decimal.Parse(dr["Ricarico"].ToString());
                    const string QueryINS = "Insert into Capitolo(IdPreventivo,NumeroCapitolo,Descrizione,Ricarico,Tipologia,PrezzoRiservato) values(@IdPreventivo,@NumeroCapitolo,@Descrizione,@Ricarico,@Tipologia,@PrezzoRiservato) SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()"; SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(QueryINS, conn, Transaction);
                    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdPreventivo", IdPreventivoLOAD);
                    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NumeroCapitolo", NumeroCapitoloLOAD);
                    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Descrizione", DescrizioneLOAD);
                    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ricarico", RicaricoLOAD);
                    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tipologia", TipologiaLOAD);
                    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PrezzoRiservato", PrezzoRiservatoLOAD);
                    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    const string QueryInsArticoli = "Insert into SottoCapitolo(IdCapitolo, Tipo, CodiceDistinta,Codice, Descrizione, DescrizioneEstesa, UnitaMisura, SottoCapitolo1, SottoCapitolo2, SottoCapitolo3, Note, RicaricoManodopera, Quantita, CostoUnitario, Images, PrezzoListino,PrezzoPersonalizzato)  SELECT (select MAX(IdCapitolo) from Capitolo ) as IdCapitolo, Tipo, CodiceDistinta,Codice, SottoCapitolo.Descrizione, DescrizioneEstesa, UnitaMisura, SottoCapitolo1, SottoCapitolo2, SottoCapitolo3, Note, RicaricoManodopera, Quantita, CostoUnitario, Images, PrezzoListino,PrezzoPersonalizzato from SottoCapitolo inner join Capitolo on Capitolo.IdCapitolo = SottoCapitolo.IdCapitolo where SottoCapitolo.IdCapitolo = @IdCapitolo group by SottoCapitolo.Tipo,SottoCapitolo.Codice,SottoCapitolo.CodiceDistinta,SottoCapitolo.Descrizione,SottoCapitolo.DescrizioneEstesa,SottoCapitolo.UnitaMisura,SottoCapitolo.SottoCapitolo1,SottoCapitolo.SottoCapitolo2,SottoCapitolo.SottoCapitolo3,SottoCapitolo.Note,SottoCapitolo.RicaricoManodopera,SottoCapitolo.Quantita,SottoCapitolo.CostoUnitario,SottoCapitolo.Images,SottoCapitolo.PrezzoListino,SottoCapitolo.PrezzoPersonalizzato,Capitolo.IdCapitolo "; SqlCommand cmdInsArticoli = new SqlCommand(QueryInsArticoli, conn, Transaction);
                    cmdInsArticoli.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdCapitolo", SqlDbType.Int).Value = IdCapitolo;
                    cmdInsArticoli.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

                Transaction.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Transaction.Rollback();
                Managementerror.SendError("Errore: " + ex);
                ret = false;
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }

            return ret;
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the timeout? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectiontimeout?view=netframework-4.8 by default it's only 30 seconds, your query is taking longer. There's also other adjustments that can be done, but not of importance to your issue you've asked.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ does `using (var _connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)){}` block would be useful here to  persist connection?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron if you're asking would a `using` block be useful here to persist connection, yes, it's not just about multiple queries though the user is doing, it's about getting rid of resources that have been allocated and making sure they are disposed of.

Comment: Yes I mean to persist connection until the query executed.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron yes, it would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can add to your **connectionString** `Connection Timeout = 30` it could work, for more information you will find an interesting link ( link below ) with all the details regarding **Connection String**

https://www.connectionstrings.com/all-sql-server-connection-string-keywords/